# how to delete all elment from Haskell Map which match a condition on their value not key?

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I want to delete all element from a `Data.Map` which match a particular condition. Let says `foobar` is this function, here is his needed behavior :

```
foobar :: (a -> Bool) -> Map k a -> Map k a
foobar (>= 20) $ fromList [("john",3),("sasha",8),("mary",33),("philip",20)] 
-- the expected result is  fromList [("john",3),("sasha",8)]
```

thanks for any reply !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Data.Map.filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Map.html#g:19)

In the future, you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+Map+k+a+-%3E+Map+k+a) to answer these questions.

Answer (score 9):

You have a desired type signature, but you don't know if there is such a function. The solution to that problem is to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), a search engine for Haskell APIs which lets you **search for functions by type**.

For example, if you [enter `(a -> Bool) -> Map k a -> Map k a` into Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+Map+k+a+-%3E+Map+k+a), the top result is [`Data.Map.filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v%3afilter), which is precisely the one you want in this case.

It's also fairly good at generalizing, so even if the type doesn't match exactly, you're still likely to find something that'll work in the top few matches.

So the next time you're looking for a function, try hoogling it first!